# How do I make sure a RSL in Flash/Flex, is loaded prior to instantiating a class that uses a shared library asset?

Tags: flash, actionscript, fonts, rsl

The issue I'm encountering is if I immediately instantiate an asset loaded that requires an asset from a RSL, sometimes the RSL has not initialized yet, and null is returned for the Font Class ArialRegular. Other times I get a "Reference Error".

How might I check for the proper initialization of an RSL and loaded assets? Checking for a null class works sometimes for when the accessed class itself returns null, but when there is instead a Reference Error checking for Null won't help.

I've used RSL for better or worse for many years so I have extensive experience with it. The problem I'm encountering seems specific to Fonts.

Solution: I answered my question below.

Comment: How are you loading your RSL? can't you just check for the existence of a class?

Comment: The RSL is loaded prior to the rest of the assets, but the assets themselves are used instantly after being loaded.

Comment: check out my answer and tell me if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've found a solution that points to a cause that cannot be corrected but can be avoided.

Basically if you have TextFields (classic, or TLF) that use the fonts you have embedded via a RSL they need to be dynamically created at run time. They cannot be a part of the original SWF asset that was loaded. Static text is OK, but dynamic and input text that requires an RSL asset messes up, unless it is dynamically generated *after* the Font asset has been loaded.

This is one of those subtle issues that I have figured out in the past, and wish I hadn't forgotten about.

Comment: ha, that seems like a bug :) with dynamic textfields that are part of the original SWF asset, have you tried resetting the `defaultTextFormat` with your RSL font? good to see you got it fixed anyway

Comment: Ah no, I haven't. I used setTextFormat() to attempt of "fix" the TextField after load with no success. I have a gut feeling this is a bug Adobe doesn't feel is worth fixing, since it has been around for at least 5 years. There is a chance it was solved, and has recently reappeared I suppose. This issue has sucked enough of my time already! I hope this post helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% on dynamic RSLs, as I tend to use static linking, so I'm not sure if you have to specifically load them yourself, or if the player does it for your automatically. In any case:

1) Loading it yourself: you should have a callback, and thus know when it's loaded 
2) Automatically loaded: you can loop every frame and check for the existence of a class that you know is in the RSL, using `getDefinitionByName()` - when it stops returning `null`, then your RSL is loaded.

Either way, if your assets require your RSL, then you're going to have to load that first, before loading the assets - it might slow down your app start up, but then, that's the nature of dependencies.

For something like a font, I'd just embed in the main SWF - as long as your not embedding the entire thing, it's not really that big; you can use the `unicodeRange` and either specify glyphs, or use the ranges defined in `flex_config.xml` file - I've written about embedding fonts here if you want to take a look at it: http://divillysausages.com/blog/as3_font_embedding_masterclass

Another thing to check when you have problems with fonts not appearing, if it multiple assets declare the same font. E.g. if swfA declares Arial with the glyphs a-z, while swfB declares Arial with the glyphs 0-9, then depending on which swf is loaded first, your textfields will only display either letters or numbers (with `embedFonts` set to true). I'm not sure if this is by design or a bug in the flash player, but it's stung me before

Comment: This is good information but doesn't solve my problem. I have updated the question to lead you to why.